# Path/file access error: LotusScript

Tags: lotusscript

I get an error

> Path/file access error

in my agent.

What is the nature of this error?

This may be happening due to kill statement. So something to do with ACL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it an schedule agent?

Comment: Without the code the answer can be only guessing... I personally think. That Richard is right, but wiout code you cannot be shure

Comment: Yes I agree without code it's only guessing. But I think I have got some clues from answers. Thanks.

Comment: I got this error trying to kill files with "unusual" characters in file name. After renaming it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Select the agent in Domino Designer and check the security tab of the Agent Properties box.  Make sure that the Restricted Operations field is set to "Allow restricted operations" or "Allow restricted operations with full administration rights". [See here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SETTING_UP_AGENT_SECURITY_USING_THE_SECURITY_TAB_OVER.html).

Also, make sure that the agent signer is granted unrestricted agent access on the Security tab of the Server Document for the server where the agent is running. [See here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/h_setup_agent_security_steps.html).

Comment: Thanks Richard for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a Path/file access error if the file doesn't exist, so check the spelling.

You might also get the error if the file is not closed.

Comment: Thanks Casper for your hints.

Answer (score 0):

Path/file access error appears when you try do access the FileSystem.
You say that the kill Command is used. 
So maybe the File, you try to delete, didnt exist or you have no write access on your Filesystem.

It has nothing to do with the ACL.